# How to certain POST array variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<input type='hidden' name='var[name1]' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='var[name2]' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='var[name3]' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='var[name4]' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='var[name5]' value='1'>
```

Now, if I need to get all these values I can use `foreach` using `$_POST['var']`.

In some situations I need to get only some of these inputs say, 'name2' and 'name5' and  `$_POST['var[name2]']` and `$_POST['var[name5]']` will not work.

What logic can be used in this scenario?

Comment: You know you can `foreach` `$_POST['var']`. Why not `print_r()` that variable and see its contents for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has a special-handling for square-brackets in postvar names: it converts them into an associative-array for you.

You can access them like so:

```
$name1 = $_POST['var']['name1']
```

See the comments on the documentation on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: You forgot `See here` section

Answer (score 3):

since `$_POST` is an array and `$_POST['var']` is another array you have to access it this way:

```
$_POST['var']['name1']
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables will be converted to an array if you use square brackets, so get them this way:

```
$_POST['var']['name2']
$_POST['var']['name5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
echo 'Value1 = '.$_POST["var"]["name1"];
echo 'Value2 = '.$_POST["var"]["name2"];
echo 'Value3 = '.$_POST["var"]["name3"];
echo 'Value4 = '.$_POST["var"]["name4"];
echo 'Value5 = '.$_POST["var"]["name5"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You print the $_POST you will see this array.

```
    Array
(
    [var] => Array
        (
            [name1] => 1
            [name2] => 1
            [name3] => 1
            [name4] => 1
            [name5] => 1
        )

)

echo $_POST['var']['name2'];
echo $_POST['var']['name5'];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do that way, the structure becomes:

```
array (
  'var' => 
    array (
      'name1' => '1' 
      'name2' => '2'
      'name3' => '3' 
      'name4' => '4' 
      'name5' => '5'
   )
)
```

So `$_POST` is an array with inner array `var` consisting of multiple associative indexes. So you need to access it as `$_POST['val']['name1']`

To get all the `var` values at once, you can loop it like:

```
foreach($_POST['var'] as $val)
{
  echo $val;
}
```